# Дублирующийся код в действиях контроллера

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Подскажите, правильно ли выносить дублирующийся код между методами контроллера в отдельные приватные методы контроллера или нужно плодить какие-то хелпер классы, или вообще существуют какие-то соглашения по этому поводу?

Answer (score 1):

Контроллер должен быть легким и являться лишь мостом между бизнес-логикой и/или данными и представлением. Необходимость писать дублирующий код между методами контроллера скорее указывает на проблемы с архитектурой, возможно данный код должен находиться на другом уровне вашей системы.

Comment: Я не к тому, что мой код сейчас дублируется, а я к тому, куда лучше выносить его, если, например, в 2 ух действиях используется неких одинаковый сегмент. Вот я и спрашиваю, правильно ли вынести его в самом контроллере в отдельный приватный метод или нет.

Comment: iluxa1810, о каком коде идет речь? Приведите хотя бы минимальный пример.

Comment: Например, валидация того, что действию контроллера были переданы корректные данные. Это может дублироваться между действиями и это куда-то нужно выносить в 1 место.

Comment: Как я писал выше, методы контроллера не должны быть перегружены никакой дополнительной логикой, в том числе вадилацией входящий данных. Валидация как правило осуществляется на клиенте средставами js, а также на сервере, но в бизнес логике, а не в контроллере.